# TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined` from the Favorites Wordpress plugin I'm using. I tried asking the plugin's creator, but got no response.

The error comes from this function:

```
plugin.setButtonData = function()
{
    plugin.data.postid = $(plugin.activeButton).attr('data-postid');
    plugin.data.siteid = $(plugin.activeButton).attr('data-siteid');
    plugin.data.favorite_count = $(plugin.activeButton).attr('data-favoritecount');
    plugin.data.site_index = plugin.utilities.siteIndex(plugin.data.siteid);
    plugin.data.site_favorites = Favorites.userFavorites[plugin.data.site_index].posts; 
    if ( plugin.data.favorite_count <= 0 ) plugin.data.favorite_count = 0;
}
```

and I've narrowed down the problem to being  that `plugin.data.site_index` (second to last line of code) returns as undefined. If I replace it with a hardcoded 1, the error goes away.

`plugin.data.site_index` is generated by the following function, which is where the original issue must be:

```
plugin.siteIndex = function(siteid)
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < Favorites.userFavorites.length; i++ ){
        if ( Favorites.userFavorites[i].site_id !== parseInt(siteid) ) continue;
        return i;
    }  
}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what could be going wrong here. Please note that I'm working in a Wordpress Multisite environment (which the plugin supports).

You can see the full JS code [here](https://github.com/kylephillips/favorites/blob/master/assets/js/favorites.js).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
plugin.data.site_favorites = Favorites.userFavorites[plugin.data.site_index].posts;
```

to

```
plugin.data.site_favorites = plugin.data.site_index >= 0 ? 
    Favorites.userFavorites[plugin.data.site_index].posts : '';
```

your code would be work.

I guess that the case when `plugin.siteIndex(siteid) return undefined` makes the problem.